# ajax replace sent object data with a string

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, loops, post

I have a loop called ids which generates a an array depending on what is in the list so it creates

```
id[one]
id[two]
id[three]...etc
```

I would want to post these with their values using ajax but seem to keep getting an error.
I have tried

```
var posts "data:allow";
for (i=0; i<ids.lengh; i=1+1) { posts=posts+", "+ids[i]+":"+id[ids[i]]; }
$.ajax({
   url: 'Posts.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: { posts }, 
   success: function(bfs) { $("#idPosts").html(bfs); }
});
```

but this comes up with "...Unexpected token }..."?

ive also tried looping in the data: bit but that error too

```
var posts ="data:allow";
$.ajax({
   url: 'Posts.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: { for (i=0; i<ids.lengh; i=1+1) { ids[i]:[ids[i]], } }, 
   success: function(bfs) { $("#idPosts").html(bfs); }
});
```

but this comes up with "...Unexpected token (..."?

Am I trying to do something that cannot be done as I don't seem to find any information about it.

thanks

EDIT ADDITIONAL....

this is what iam trying to work with,

function fnFunc(){

```
var ids = [ "Page", "FirstName", "LastName" ];
var id = [];
for ( var i=0; i<ids.length; i=i+1 ) {
    id.push(ids[i]);
    id[ids[i]]=$("#id"+ids[i]).val(); if ( id[ids[i]]=="" ){ id[id[i]]=$("#id"+ids[i]).text(); }
}

var posts ="data:allow";
$.ajax({
    url: 'Posts.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        for (i=0; i<ids.length; i=1+1) { ids[i]:[ids[i]], }
    }, 
    success: function(bfs) { $("#idPosts").html(bfs); }
});
```

}

Comment: All errors possibility depends upon your code show your webservice

Comment: You can post an object or string or array, do not mix that up! If you send a string than it should look like this: `data=allow&var1=val1&var2=val2`

Comment: Should be `length` not `lengh`

Comment: There is a spelling mistake ids.length instead of ids.lengh. This might cause the error

Comment: sorry? what do you mean by "show your web service", ta

Comment: i have corrected the spelling mistake, but still errors?

Comment: Also use `var posts = "data=allow"` (note equal sign @ 2 places), than add new vars with `posts+="&newvar=newval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data: { posts }` is not valid javascript.

An objet literal is built of a key and a value (e.g `{posts: posts}`)

If you are trying to send a string you probably want `data: posts`, or even better:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'Posts.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: 'data:allow, ' + $.param(id), 
   success: function(bfs) { $("#idPosts").html(bfs); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think its because of this

```
data: { for (i=0; i<ids.lengh; i=1+1) { ids[i]:[ids[i]], } },
```

why not just pass `id` as your `data`

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'Posts.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: id, 
   success: function(bfs) { $("#idPosts").html(bfs); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var posts = "data:allow";
    for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) { posts=posts+", "+ids[i]+":"+id[ids[i]]; }
    $.ajax({
       url: 'Posts.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: { posts : posts }, 
       success: function(bfs) { $("#idPosts").html(bfs); }
    });
```

There is a couple of syntax errors in the original. posts = "", 
remember to declare 'i' or it will be global. 
The length spelling mistake.
Also in the example i will always increment and stay 2. Is this intentional?

What is the variable ids? Is it an array of objects or an array of integers?... if it is objects then the code should be something like:

posts=posts+", "+ids[i].id+":"+id[ids[i]].value;

What your "data" in the ajax request, should look like, depends on what your server expects. You could just set posts as the data value.

**Updated code:**
In your update I see you fixed all the initial syntax errors. Based off your description I think you are looking for something like this.

Whether you just send the data as an array to the server or whether you need to stringify it or set it as a property, would depend on what your server expects.

```
var ids = [ "Page", "FirstName", "LastName" ];
var data = [];
for ( var i=0; i<ids.length; i=i+1 ) {
    var value = $("#id"+ids[i]).val(); 
    if ( !value  ){
        value = $("#id"+ids[i]).text(); 
    }   
    var obj = {};
    obj[ids[i]] = value;
    data.push(obj);   

}

var posts ="data:allow";
$.ajax({
    url: 'Posts.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data , //{ data : JSON.stringify(data) }
    success: function(bfs) { $("#idPosts").html(bfs); }
});
```